# MySQL retrieving an int written to a timestamp field

Tags: mysql, sql, database, timestamp

I'm working with imported data that included an integer that was mistakenly mapped and written to a column of type timestamp. I'm trying to get the original int out of the timestamp field.

If I try to CAST the timestamp back to an UNSIGNED, I get integers that appear to be of the form YYYYMMDDHHMMSS. So it appears the original integer is now lost due to the conversion that occurred when writing to the table. Is there any way to get the original integer back after converting it to a timestamp?

Comment: Most probably: nope, you can't. When trying to insert a integer into a timestamp all I get is `[HY000][1292] Incorrect datetime value: '42454344' for column 'val' at row 1` and `[22001][1292] Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '42454344' for column 'val' at row 1`

Comment: Right. Interesting that it didn't error out when they did the import. Maybe because the integers are small - range from 1-13000. Converting to unsigned gives almost all values in the year 2000. e.g. 20001224160000, though there are a couple 1999 and 2001.

Comment: Tried first to insert `42` which seems to be in your range, but MySQL refuses to insert `42`, `'42'` and `CAST(42 AS UNSIGNED)`. If they did use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` you may try [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) though manual states that it might return a different number.